# JavaScript: Button in a table view

Tags: javascript, titanium

i have a problem with button inside TableViewRow - with **info_button**. This button is created on each row of TableViewRow in for cyklus. When i click it, it works fine, open alert dialog as i want to, but then it opens also the code which belongs to tableView Row. 
(I cut unimportant piece of code, so there are maybe some mistakes, but it works fine)

```
var url = "http://hotel.010.sk/skyfit/mysql.php";
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var tableData = [];
var json, harmonogram, vypis, i, row, nameLabel, nickLabel, cvicenie, harmon, backLabel;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload: function() {
// Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


for (i = 0; i < json.harmonogram.length; i++) {
    vypis = json.harmonogram[i];


    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:80,
        hasChild:true, 
        url:'tab1.js'

    });

var info_button =  Titanium.UI.createButton({
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE,
    right: '5dp',
    top: 5,
    //buttonid : i 
    id: "image"
});
```

Here is my info_button, I need to open only this piece of code

```
info_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

          var about = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'O cvičení',
            message: vypis.nazov,
            buttonNames: ['OK']
    });
    about.show();

});

//here is CODE for some LABELS, its not important for my problem


row.add(nameLabel);
row.add(nickLabel);
row.add(info_button);
tableData.push(row);


   };


table.setData(tableData);
},
onerror: function(e) {
Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
},
timeout:5000
});


xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

And it opens also this Listener and I need to open only info_button if user click on it.

```
**table.addEventListener**('click', function(e) {


//here is code for Listener

}); 

win.add(table);

win.open();
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **bubbleParent** property of button to **false**.

for example :-

```
Var info_button =  Titanium.UI.createButton({
        bubbleParent: false
});
```